# Extract date from a string using Talend

Tags: csv, talend

I am receiving CSV files daily which have header like 
"AD PERFORMANCE REPORT (Jan 24, 2016)".
I would like to extract date from it and use it as date column using Talend.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For change the format of a specicif column in other format, you can use the "tExtractRegexFields", with your regex for get just your date.

```
tFileInputDelimited --> tExtractRegexFields --> tMap --> tFileOutputDelimited
```

After get the date in your string with the 'tExtractRegexFields' component, you can specifyy the type of date in your output Schema like that :

[image]

the pattern of your date (Jan 24, 2016) is "**MMM d, yyyy**"

link for tExtractRegexField on Talend is [here](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/18.10+tExtractRegexFields)

link for a great website for test your regex is [here](http://www.regexpal.com/93400)

link for date Pattern in Jav is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

I used the following regex in tExtractRegexFields

"\(([^)]*)\)"